# Strange fragment issue Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a save button on each of the fragments, when the  save button is pressed the data is saved to a getter/setter class and on the last fragment the save button sends all the data to a sqlite database.. I have a strange problem on fragment 7 the data will not be saved until I go the last fragment and then back to fragment 7.. any ideas.. its driving me crazy lol.. heres some snippets of my code ..

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (i == 0) {
        fragment = new Personal_Details();

    }
    if (i == 1) {
        fragment = new Doctors_Details();

    }
  }
}
// this continues for all the fragments
```

then in the fragement class I have the following

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    dbcon = new DBTools(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
```

No errrors comeup in the logcat , it does save but only when I go to the last and back to frag 7.. any sugegstions.. thanks

Comment: "then in the fragement class i have the following" I see no code whatsoever from your part. Is that supposed to be?

Comment: im wondering is the problem with this line  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); do i need to have that line of code inevery fragement activity class ?

Comment: You need to provide way more code. The code you exposes actually exposes almost nothing that we can truly investigate.

Comment: How much have you played around with breakpoints and debugging to see if certain lines of code are even being run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding code to the following method

```
    @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
Log.v("TEST","TEST");
super.onAttach(activity);
dbcon = new DBTools(activity);
```

}

sorted the problem out..